# Converting String to double in java. Change format of printed double

Tags: java, csv

I am reading a following CSV file in java and

```
1191196800.681 - !AIVDM,1,1,,,13aG?N0rh20E6sjN1J=9d4<00000,0*1D
```

Here is my code to read this CSV file and convert the 1st column of the CSV file (which is a String) to a double

```
public class ReadCSV {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    try {
        BufferedReader CSVFile = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(
                "C:\\example.txt"));

        try {
            String dataRow = CSVFile.readLine();

            while (dataRow != null) {
                String[] dataarray = dataRow.split("-");

                String temp = dataarray[0];

                double i = Double.parseDouble(temp);

                System.out.println(temp);
                System.out.println(i);
                dataRow = CSVFile.readLine();

            }

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

}

When I execute the code I get the following values

```
1191196800.681 
1.191196800681E9
```

Why is the value of variable "temp" and "i" not the same. What changes must I do in the code to get the following values:

```
1191196800.681 
1191196800.681
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Don't print it in the default scientific notation? Try printf/format.

Comment: `1.191196800681E9 == 1191196800.681`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yups vizier is correct what you need to do is this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    String dataRow = "1191196800.681";


        String[] dataarray = dataRow.split("-");

        String temp = dataarray[0];
        DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("#.###");
        double i = Double.parseDouble(temp);

        System.out.println(temp);
        System.out.println(df.format(i));

}
```

Answer (score 7):

temp and i are exactly the same, just the double value is formatted in scientific notation. You can format it differently if you like using [DecimalFormat](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/text/DecimalFormat.html) for instance.

Answer (score 0):

The other result is in scientific notation, but is the same.

If you want change the representation you can use `String.format("%.3f", i)`, which represents the number with 3 decimals